Drawing a BCE diagram in springboot
I am tasked in my assignment do draw a bce diagram based on my springboot application. But i am not very sure which class should be the boundary. I believe controller class is controller itself , and entity itself as well.
I was assuming the boundary is the HTML pages but im not very sure as well
